# Computationally intensive scala process using actors hangs uncooperatively

Tags: scala, jvm

I have a computationally intensive scala application that hangs.  By hangs I means it is sitting in the process stack using 1% CPU but does not respond to kill -QUIT nor can it be attached via jdb attach.
Runs 2-12 hours at 800-900% CPU before it gets stuck
The application is using ~10 scala.actors.

Until now I have had great success with kill -QUIT but I am bit stumped as to how to proceed.

The actors write a fair amount to stdout using println which is redirected to a text file but has not been helpful so far diagnostically.
I am just hoping there is some obvious technique when kill -QUIT fails that I am ignorant of. 
Or just confirmation that having multiple actors println asynchronously is a real bad idea (though I've been doing it for a long time only recently with these results)
Details
scala 2.8.1 & 2.8.0
mac osx 10.6.5
java version "1.6.0_22"

Thanks

Comment: Never use System.out or System.err in a multithreaded setting, it's shared blocking IO. Use Logback or log4j or something more sensible.

Comment: Never completely figured this out.  Problem may have been related to array of object references being re-used improperly (less then conclusive but I have to move on)  Also discovered that some errant code was hammering a synchronized map with getOrElseUpdate requests, which I fixed but I would prefer to believe that not to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna remove the process from the run queue, the obvious choice is

```
kill -9
```

Of course you wanna avoid having to do that in the first place, but you do not provide any information that would allow us to help you with that. Writing to stdout in multiple actors is indeed a bad idea, but the worst thing that could come from that is garbled output.

Answer (score 0):

Most times I have seen the JVM react like that is when it goes into no permgen space. It will then be incapable of anything (even dying). You don't find any traces of that in your printout? Have you tried to increase the permgen space?

Comment: Increasing permgen space to various higher values has not fixed the problem. though things I found searching for stuff about it was interesting, in particular -XX:+UseParallelGC and -XX:+AggressiveHeap They both sound good but they have not helped either :(

Comment: Do you see any increase in memory use during the time the application is running?

Comment: How would you measure it.  Prior to hang ps looks something like

Comment: ps aux says before and after hanging it's taking about 8.5 % of memory on a 16 Gig machine.  top gives me a bunch more specific stuff, but seems same before and after a hang.  I'm using -Xms64m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: ps and top is very bad at showing java memory usage. Instead check out java.lang.management.ManagementFactory (memory pool jmx beans) and log it yourself.